# How do I configure my DNS record? - MeteorJS

Tags: meteor, cname, meteor-galaxy

How do i configure my DNS record to point to galaxy?

I bought a domain with the following attributes:
Type: CNAME Record
Host: www

I am kinda lost here, I don't know where I should actually configure my DNS. In my project, or the website I registered my domain in? and how?

The following is my host records:
[image: HOSTS RECORDS]

Answer (score 0):

#### In Galaxy

1. Log into galaxy
2. Click on your app.
3. Click on `settings`.
4. In domains, click `add new domain` and enter your domain
5. In the description for the Domains and Encryption section you will see an address that looks something like `us-east-1.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com`. Copy this down.

#### On your host

1. Create a new custom resource record `Name: *`, `Type: CNAME`, Data: `us-east-1.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com` (or paste yours if it differs in galaxy).
2. Create a new custom resource record `Name: www`, `Type: CNAME`, Data: `us-east-1.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com` (or paste yours if it differs in galaxy).

Let me know if you have any questions! There is a bit more to a full deployment, the docs on http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-guide.html go in depth on how to setup everything else.

Comment: I edited my question and added my hosts records, can you please check if I am doing it right? -_-

Comment: Remove the unmasked redirects, those aren't needed as Galaxy has all of that configured on their side. When you add your domain to Galaxy it will do this for you. Then create another CNAME record like you did with the `www` but this time with a `*` instead of the `www`, so - `CNAME Record, *, us-east-1.galaxy-ingress.meteor.com.` Also I tend to set my TTL to `1m` instead of `30m`, but that's up to you.

Comment: thanks, mind if I asked what is the difference between unmasked, masked, and permanent (301)? :)